# How to send http request via ssdp in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ssdp

I am following this tutorial:
https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+API 
...trying to grab a list of devices via ssdp / http get.

```html
        let query: string = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
            "HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\n" +
            "MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\n" +
            "ST: roku: ecp\r\n\r\n";

        this.http
            .get(query)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
            (data) => this.devices = data,
            (err) => this.error = err);
```

... but I'm getting a 404 error (also, localhost is being appended to the string):

```html
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

```html
http://localhost:52125/M-SEARCH%20*%20HTTP/1.1HOST:%20239.255.255.250:1900MAN:%20%22ssdp:discover%22ST:%20roku:%20ecp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSDP uses HTTPU or HTTP over UDP. Node's HTTP client only sends data over TCP. You'll need to use a udp socket to send this manually and listen for data, or use a pre-existing library such as [`node-ssdp`](https://github.com/diversario/node-ssdp).

Comment: Thanks. Have you used node-ssdp? I am having trouble getting it up and running in my project: 

TS Property 'Client' does not exist on type '{}'

Comment: looks like node-ssdp is a dead-end because of its dependency on dgram (which no longer exists). I will have to look into udp sockets, I guess.

Comment: That looks very promising! I will check it out tonight.

Comment: Thanks again for your responses and ideas. I am still learning this client-side development and what I have found is that some of the node modules will not work in the browser without additional configuration. So, for example: the node-roku package was written to only run in a node.js server (not inside chrome). This may seem obvious to others -- but it is something I did not consider. I am going to mark your answer as the solution because it is correct.

Comment: Depending on the solution you're after, You may be able to build a small express server to proxy the `node.js` only modules to your browser. So you would build the roku integration in node, then present a web interface in chrome to control the roku device across the network. The other alternative would be to use `electron` as it is basically a browser with both execution environments.

Comment: hmmm... my initial thought was a browser-based solution (I am experimenting with Progressive Web Apps)... but electron looks interesting.